# Elixir: how to make a custom type implement ==, <, and >

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Background: I'm working on converting this F# discriminated union to Elixir:

```f#
type Suit =
| Diamonds
| Clubs
| Hearts
| Spades
```

I know there are a few different ways to do that, and that's not my question.

The following need to be true:

```
Diamonds == Diamonds
Diamonds < Hearts
Spades > Hearts
```

I was surprised to find that Elixir doesn't have a comparable protocol similar to Haskell's `Ord` typeclass and this [implementation](https://github.com/coingaming/comparable) on GitHub (with very few stars!)

Is there a well-accepted or idiomatic way to make custom types comparable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to simply provide `equal?/2` and/or `compare/2` in the module that defines the custom type. This can be seen frequently in the core libraries and robust third-party libraries.

For example, [`Date.compare/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#compare/2) has the following specification

```elixir
compare(Calendar.date(), Calendar.date()) :: :lt | :eq | :gt
```

---

Starting with `v1.10.0`, *Elixir* provides handy sorting with [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#sort/2-sorting-structs) for structs implementing `compare/2`:

```elixir
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:name]
  def compare(%User{name: n1}, %User{name: n2}) when n1 < n2,
    do: :lt
  def compare(%User{name: n1}, %User{name: n2}) when n1 > n2,
    do: :gt
  def compare(%User{}, %User{}), do: :eq
end

users = [
  %User{name: "john"},
  %User{name: "joe"},
  %User{name: "jane"}
]

Enum.sort(users, {:asc, User})
#⇒ [%User{name: "jane"},
#   %User{name: "joe"},
#   %User{name: "john"}]
```